# Make a Discord bot reply when a user sends an image in chat

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a working discord bot that responds to people and I'm even getting it to tell me the weather and time of a specific zip code through a slash command. But I'm having trouble getting it to reply when someone sends an image.

I want the discord bot to replay with "Looks like someone is sending..." when a user uploads an image in a channel. Can anyone help a brotha out?

I found a few solutions but they're like 5+ years old and I'm not getting anywhere with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by detecting the message from `Event` [`MessageCreate`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/Client:Class#messageCreate).

Your message has a property [`attachments`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/Message:Class#attachments) that return a new [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/collection/1.5.3/Collection:Class).

After that, you can simply check if the message is a file or not.

It would look something like this:

```js
const { Events } = require('discord.js');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.MessageCreate,
    async execute(message) {
        if (message.channel.id === YOUR_CHANNEL_ID && message.attachments.size > 0) {
            const attachment = message.attachments.first();
            const extension = path.extname(attachment.name).toLowerCase();

            if (extension === ".png") {
                await message.channel.send();
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```